# Can´t use GROUP BY after WHERE clause into subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
left JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM ##TTA TT WHERE (TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0A' OR  TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0EXPT')) TT
GROUP BY TT.DATAAREAID, tt.VOUCHER, TT.MAINACCOUNTID 
AS TTIVA0A ON Asiento.Asiento = TTIVA0A.VOUCHER 
AND Asiento.Cuenta = TTIVA0A.AD
AND Asiento.Empresa = TTIVA0A.DATAAREAID
```

Problem is into GROUP BY clause I get:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Can someone explain me why I cant use `GROUP BY` after `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Please include the entire query. Queries don't begin with `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Because your group by is outside of your subquery. Move the parenthesis and this is no longer an issue.

Comment: I don't see the WHERE -- I see a join.   You will need a `ON` before the `GROUP BY` or you will get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were more careful with your formatting this would be painfully obvious.

Here is your code with the group by in the right place.

```
left JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM ##TTA TT 
    WHERE TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0A' 
        OR  TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0EXPT'
    GROUP BY TT.DATAAREAID
        , TT.VOUCHER
        , TT.MAINACCOUNTID 
) AS TTIVA0A ON Asiento.Asiento = TTIVA0A.VOUCHER 
    AND Asiento.Cuenta = TTIVA0A.AD
    AND Asiento.Empresa = TTIVA0A.DATAAREAID
```

Comment: It would probably be good to note that way the sub query is written (SELECT *) it assumes that TT.DTAREAID and TT.VOUCHER, and TT MAINACCOUNTID are the only columns in the table or this still wont work

Comment: Agreed @Matt. There are many things there I would probably do a little differently (and safely)